# Observable.Timer(DateTimeOffset) Process Exit

Tags: wpf, system.reactive, datetimeoffset

I have a Observable.Timer(TimeSpan) multiple times, but in couple of places I have used Observable.Timer(DateTimeOffset) to trigger the event at that time, but I believe it is stopping my process from exiting.

```
DateTimeOffset offset = new DateTimeOffset(minStart);

Observable.Timer(offset)
   .Subscribe(_ =>
   {
      UpdateActive();
   });
```

This piece of code is in my ViewModel and on Window Closed, the process is still running in the background, normally wherever I use the Observable.Timer(TimeSpan) they gets disposed automatically, why doesn't this?

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug? Or am I missing something?

Comment: can't you stop the timer in the window closed event?

Comment: Nothing ever gets disposed of automatically by the .NET framework. You must explicitly ensure that all `IDisposable` references are disposed. The Rx framework helps by disposing completed subscriptions for you, but you must dispose all that have not naturally completed.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using one of the `Subscribe()` extension methods, assuming you're using a recent version of RX, the observable should be releasing any subscribers when it completes. Is your observable completing in one case but not the other?

If your observable has not completed (i.e. if the time represented by `offset` hasn't happened yet) by the time you close your window, nothing is going to automatically unsubscribe for you. Here's what the [introtorx site](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/03_LifetimeManagement.html) has to say on this matter (emphasis mine):

> Considering this, I thought it was prudent to note that subscriptions
>   will not be automatically disposed of. You can safely assume that the
>   instance of IDisposable that is returned to you does not have a
>   finalizer and will not be collected when it goes out of scope. **If you
>   call a Subscribe method and ignore the return value, you have lost
>   your only handle to unsubscribe. The subscription will still exist,
>   and you have effectively lost access to this resource, which could
>   result in leaking memory and running unwanted processes.**

Answer (score 0):

Using the overload of `Observable.Timer` that accepts `DateTimeOffset` will not on it's own cause a process to be held open; something else is responsible for this.

However, the consequence of not disposing subscriptions to `Observable.Timer` is that you will leak the timer resource.

You should retain the `IDisposable` subscription handles for timer and event based observables and dispose them appropriately; most WPF frameworks provide a suitable event for this.

In general, I track and dispose of all my window-scoped subscriptions, just to be on the safe side. See [Convert Polling Web Service to RX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063941/convert-polling-web-service-to-rx/21064194#21064194) for an example.